# How to refresh a div on a click on a button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I need your help in doing the ajax part to refresh the div on the click on the "Refresh" button. I need an example.

I have tried to do it to be refreshed evey 15 seconds as per an example I found it in the internet.

but it did not work, can you please help

Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function Ajax(){  
    var xmlHttp;  
    try{      
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari  
    }  
    catch (e){  
        try{  
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer  
        }  
        catch (e){  
            try{  
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
            }  
            catch (e){  
                alert("No AJAX!?");  
                return false;  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){  
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){  
            document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;  
            setTimeout('Ajax()',10000);  
        }  
    }  
    xmlHttp.open("GET","MQSTATUS.jsp",true);  
    xmlHttp.send(null);  
}  

window.onload=function(){  
    setTimeout('Ajax()',10000);  
}  
</script>
```

it is giving me an error which is unknown runtime error in the line

```
<code>
    xmlHttp.open("GET","MQSTATUS.jsp",true); 
</code>
```

How should I modify the code, I tried to change the naming and do some modifications, but it did not work. I tried to put / before the url

```
<code>
    xmlHttp.open("GET","/MQSTATUS.jsp",true); </code>
```

Comment: You tagged your question with jquery-ajax. Why don't you use jquery, then? It has shortcut methods just for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by separating the initialization and updating of the XHR object and AJAX call. This way you only have the one XHR object and it does what you tell it to do, all the time.
First you initialize the XHR object from the onload handler of the window object. Then you issue new requests to this object by calling `updateAjax()` in the  `onclick` handler of your refresh button. It will look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlHttp;

function initAjax() {
    try {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    } catch(e) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
        } catch(e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                alert("No AJAX!?");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}

function updateAjax() {
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "MQSTATUS.jsp", true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

window.onload = function() {
    initAjax();
}
</script>
```

And then in your HTML put

```
<input type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="updateAjax()" />
```

Hope this helps you a little.

Comment: I tried but it did not work. It is still showing the unknown runtime error and referencing to the link

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://designgala.com/how-to-refresh-div-using-jquery/) can be what you're looking for, using jquery. [Here](http://www.designgala.com/demos/divref/a3.html)'s the example (which you can also find in the previous link)

Other searches on google show the same approach: you "hide" somehow the div and you load the content into it again and display it, by chaining the operations needed. I don't think, however, that you can do it with only javascript, you need an external library (like jquery)

Comment: As jQuery is a JavaScript library you can't do anything with it that can't be done in JavaScript without jQuery.

Comment: hum, i was just meaning that with jquery is easy, but it turned out not so well :)

Comment: Agreed, jQuery makes things easy, but I think it's a bit much to load the entire library just for doing a little bit of AJAX. Also, I don't think you should hide the div for updating, it should work just as well by just loading the new content.

Comment: I guess it's just an effect to help the user being aware of what's going on

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but I think you should first remove setTimeout('Ajax()',10000);  inside your AJAX call.
Secondly, try adding the full deployed path of this jsp.
ie. if you have a deploy path of http://localhost:8080/MYAPPLICATION/MQSTATUS.jsp, then try with xmlHttp.open("GET","/MYAPPLICATION/MQSTATUS.jsp",true);

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an 'UpdatePanel' AJAX control to the button control. add this kind of code On Click event of button:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>        
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Timer ID="timer1" Interval="500" runat="server" ontick="timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
            <%--<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />--%>
        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```